# Connection refused in mongodb macvlan docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a raspberry Pi4 with docker installed and mongo Docker in macvlan mode.

And from my desktop computer I ping the docker IP and response well, but when I try to access the mongodb server with other docker in this computer, it fails.

It's impossible to connect from other docker in same network that macvlan is present.

This is my docker network inspect output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ docker network inspect pablo1
[
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "f17210b2cf26b2752e03b2a4c889041ab9be3a8746675e29e2104362409c8039": {
                "Name": "mongo",
                "EndpointID": "6aedeff51378d8a8f5f6ebc7533306edcd21a3324f5dff319e5bbed5736df5d4",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:c4",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.196/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "parent": "eth0"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

this is my Dockerfile to make the Docker container:

```
FROM armv7/armhf-ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mongodb

RUN apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get autoclean -y && \
    apt-get clean -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Environment variables
RUN echo " " >> /etc/bash.bashrc && \
    echo "#_____________________" >> /etc/bash.bashrc && \
    echo "force_color_prompt=yes" >> /etc/bash.bashrc && \
    echo "alias cls='clear'" >> /etc/bash.bashrc && \
    echo "export TERM=linux" >> /etc/bash.bashrc

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/data/db"]

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

COPY mongodb.conf /etc/
# Define default command.

# Expose ports.
#   - 27017: process
#   - 28017: http

RUN cat /etc/mongodb.conf
RUN ls -las /etc

CMD ["mongod"]

EXPOSE 27017
EXPOSE 28017
```

And this is part of Docker mongodb mongodb.conf

```
# mongodb.conf

# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this problem occurs only when the database directory is mounted in NFS external partition